# Publist BiblaTeX problem

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-publist

I tried a Long time now to use publist BiblaTeX to produce a separate reference list and failed. Ultimately I used a code example (see further below) from the web (right in this forum) but it won't work either. The Errors reported were:

> ```
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
> The top-level auxiliary file: publist_test.aux
> I found no \citation commands---while reading file publist_test.aux
> I found no \bibdata command---while reading file publist_test.aux
> I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file publist_test.aux
> (There were 3 error messages)
>
> Process exited with error(s)
> ```

The example code I used follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bibstyle=publist]{biblatex}

\plauthorname{Frank}
\begin{filecontents}{mwebib.bib}

@Article{Frank1994e,
    author  = {Frank, Andrew U. and Timpf, Sabine},
    title   = {Multiple Representations for Cartographic Objects in a Multi-Scale Tree - An Intelligent Graphical Zoom},
    journal = {Computers and Graphics Special Issue on Modelling and Visualization of Spatial Data in GIS},
    year    = {1994},
    volume  = {18},
    number  = {6},
    pages   = {823--829},
}

@Article{Buyong1991,
    author  = {Buyong, Taher and Kuhn, Werner and Frank, Andrew U.},
    title   = {A Conceptual Model of Measurement-Based Multipurpose Cadastral Systems},
    journal = {Journal of the Urban and Regional Information Systems Association (URISA)},
    year    = {1991},
    volume  = {3},
    number  = {2},
    pages   = {35--49},
}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\title{XX publications}
\author{}
\date{\today}
\maketitle


\section{Articles}
\newrefsection[mwebib]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none]  


\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 explains how you can set up your editor to run Biber for you. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 contains some general background on what Biber and BibTeX do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the package `biblatex`, you have to decide on whether to use `bibtex` or `biber` as the external program for processing the `*bib` files and for sorting the entries. By default, `biblatex` uses `biber`, and also tells you so in the log file. `Biber` is nowadays considered the standard backend and `bibtex` only a 'legacy backend'. Some advanced `biblatex` features are only available with `biber` and the `biblatex` documentation works under the assumption that `biber` is used. Unless there are very good reasons to use BibTeX one should use `biber` with `biblatex`.

**Using `biblatex` with `bibtex`**

In the preamble, load `biblatex` with the option `backend=bibtex`:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=publist,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

Then run `pdflatex main` (assuming  that your document is in the file `main.tex`).

Now you will find something like the following at the end of `main.log`:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s):
(biblatex)                main1-blx
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

After running `bibtex main1-blx`, rerun `pdflatex main` one more time to get the bibliography, and a second time to get references to the bibliography right.

**Using `biblatex` with `biber`**

In the preamble, load `biblatex` without the`backend` option:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=publist]{biblatex}
```

Then run `pdflatex main` (assuming  that your document is in the file `main.tex`).

Now you will find something like the following at the end of `main.log`:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                main
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

After running `biber main`, rerun `pdflatex main` one more time to get the bibliography, and a second time to get references to the bibliography right.

Comment: Just to add that while one can choose between Biber and BibTeX, Biber is nowadays considered the standard backend and BibTeX only a 'legacy backend'. Some advanced `biblatex` featrures are only available with Biber and the `biblatex` documentation works under the assumption that Biber is used. Unless there are very good reasons to use BibTeX one should use Biber with `biblatex`.

Comment: @moewe I shamelessly copied your comment into my answer. Thank you ...